# How to reduce big size database files (Data File ) SQL Server without SHRINK?

Tags: sql-server, disk-space, storage, shrink, data

I found a couple of 'question' regarding shrinking big datafiles but I think that is not very accurate to my situation. So here is my question

I have a big database with almost 8TB of Data File Size and almost 160 GB of log file
The database is in offline status

Shrink process due to the big size of the data file will take a long time so I'm not sure how to proceed in order to avoid any problem in the instance.

One option that I have in mind is to create a new data file and then, copy the tables to the new data files and finally shrink the old data file

Best regards

Comment: You mention the database is offline. Can it be brought online? You won't be able to do anything without bringing the database online. Additionally, how much space is actually being used within your data files (which you'll need to bring the database online to find out)?

Answer (score 0):

Is there actually 8 TB of data in the database? If so, then even shrinking can't help you, that's the legitimate size of the database. Though you could look into [**Data Compression**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver15) for your largest tables to help minimize the space they consume on disk.

Comment: Some of the big tables are already compressed others not.
I inherited it from old equipment but for sure will need put back online the database if need do stuff on it.
 
But as far as I know compress big table may can last for a long time right?

Comment: @SakZepelin The initial compression of the entire Table could take a while, and can potentially be resource intensive during it, yes.